# Is there a limit to what magic in the HP world can do?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, spells

We know that powerful wizards can create spells. Snape has created Sectumsempra, and all.

**Is there any limit on what kind of spell they can create?**

Would it be possible to:

- Say, if a wizard wants to create a spell that kills 10 people at once, is it possible?
- Or if a wizard wants to create a spell which rises the dead from their grave and gives them proper life, can he do it?

Want more? 
 - A spell to write code, please I am in imminent need of it :P...

Comment: It would be completely impossible to have a meaningful tale if there were no limits on the powers of magic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are already spells that can kill multiple people. The spells they create are governed only by the laws of magic. The fundamental laws of magic by Aldabert Waffling.

> Adalbert Waffling's Fundamental Laws of Magic: Tamper with the deepest mysteries -- the source of life, the essence of self -- only if prepared for consequences of the most extreme and dangerous kind.

He cannot and no wizard or witch can ever raise the dead and give them proper life at least not in the Harry Potter Universe. Neither the Resurrection Stone can and the other evidence we have of it is the Inferi which are evil undead zombie wizards. (the things in the lake in Voldemorts cave)

I can't and no one bar JKR can be exact in saying what the Limits are as we are never told we know of few things that cannot be accomplished through magic and raising the dead with actual life is one of them. One can imagine that Love will be one as it is explained that love potions do not cause actual love but merely an obsession. Food cannot be conjured out of thin air but only summoned. That is however one of the Exceptions within Gamps Laws not Adalberts.

Can also see more here: [Is Harry Potter's magic random, "mathematical" or does it have its own personality?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58394/is-harry-potters-magic-random-mathematical-or-does-it-have-its-own-personali/58397#58397)

Comment: They already have Quick-Quotes Quill which will write as you go and it appears they are able to know what the user wants to write down as we see with Rita Skeeter so reason that couldn't be adopted to a Typewriter or Keyboard.

Comment: If I have to type this - `for (i=0; i!=2; i++){console.log(sqrt(i));}` - how would I say it? And how would it be typed in a computer? Its no good to see code written on a piece of parchment with ink... IT WON'T EXECUTE!

Comment: I think you would think it or the keyboard would know how to intialise a for loop.

Answer (score 4):

From *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows,* Chapter 15, The Goblin's Revenge:

> Hermione: "Your mother can’t produce food out of thin air, no one can. Food is the first of the five Principal Exceptions to Gamp’s Law of Elemental Transfigura—"
>
> Ron: "Oh, speak English, can’t you?"
>
> Hermione: "It’s impossible to make good food out of nothing! You can Summon it if you know where it is, you can transform it, you can increase the quantity if you’ve already got some..."

About [Gamp's Law of Elemental Tranformation](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gamp%27s_Law_of_Elemental_Transfiguration):

> Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration is a law governing the magical world. There are five Principle Exceptions to Gamp's Law; the only one explicitly stated is food - however, there are a number of possible candidates for the remaining four.
>
> It should be noted that while food cannot be outright created from nothing, it can be multiplied if one already has some food to multiply, it can be enlarged or the food can be summoned if one knows the approximate location and is fairly sure the food will still be there.[1](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gamp%27s_Law_of_Elemental_Transfiguration)
>
> In September 1997, after Ron commented that his mother could make good food out of thin air, Hermione stated that this was impossible, as food is one of the five Principle Exemptions to this law, but this only irritated Ron, who wanted her to "speak English", but was not satisfied by her explanation.[2]
>
> On 1 May, 1998, after Neville Longbottom noted that the one thing that the Room of Requirement did not seem to be able to provide was food, Ron commented that food was one of the five Principle Exceptions to this law, to "general astonishment".[3]