# Is the water from the Aqua spell consumable?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

*The title is pretty clear by itself.*

**Is the water that is being produced by the Aqua spell consumable?**

Comment: I like to think that it just condenses the water found in atmosphere so it should be consumable but it is only speculation, I could be wrong.

Comment: @Aegon hmmm that is a more mechanical aproach I would say, dont forget we are talking about magic here.... so the water is being magically created not transformed....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, at least Harry thought so.

> ‘Aguamenti!’ he shouted, jabbing the goblet with his wand.
>   The goblet filled with clear water; Harry dropped to his
>   knees beside Dumbledore, raised his head and brought the
>   glass to his lips – but it was empty. Dumbledore groaned and
>   began to pant.
>
> ‘But I had some – wait – Aguamenti!’ said Harry again, pointing his
>   wand at the goblet.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes, according to *Wonderbook: Book of Spells.*

> The Water-Making Spell conjures clean, drinkable water from the end of the wand.

[Thanks to Ibid for the quote.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40294/89771)